# Heuristics for Square-free Proof?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, primorial

I like to waste my time on long-standing unsolved problems - the choice this week is the square-free nature of $1+p_n\#$, where $p_n\#$ is the $n$-th primorial.

The question here is short: does anyone know of a heuristic to measure potential proofs regarding this statement or others like it against?

(I'm nowhere close to a proof but if I want to get there I should know what I'm up against... Thanks in advance!!)

Comment: Please excuse my lack of LaTex... Forgive me, Father, for I have sinned

Comment: Thank you gracious mod who fixed my LaTex!

Comment: Choice of the week? How many "long-standing unsolved problems" do you solve within a week?

Comment: @Anybody "too many to fit in this margin", lol. I'm just using this week in a manner of speaking

Comment: Is this an open problem mentioned somewhere (for example in wikipedia) or a statement from which you do not know whther it is true ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"a heuristic to measure potential proofs"*? If you have a potential proof, you can check whether it is in fact a proof, right?

Comment: @Sneezeburgers Not only mods can edit a post. Usually someone edits a post , in particular if only minor improvements are necessary. The most important thing is anyway not the use of Latex, but to present context, in this case , if you found the problem somewhere or had the idea for this conjecture yourself. If $q$ is a prime and $q^2\mid p_n$#$+1$ for some $p_n$ , then $q\ge 2\cdot 10^6$. This is promising.

Comment: @Servaes For example, a well known and good heuristic for the Collatz problem is to test your proof on the negative integers

Comment: @Sneezeburgers I'm sorry, I still have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @Servaes I worded the first response poorly. Suppose you have a proof that no cycles other than the 4-2-1 cycle exist (in the Collatz problem). A way to test if the proof is flawed (not necessarily to check if it's right!) is to use it on the negative integers, as there are two non-trivial cycles. If your proof for no cycles also works over the negatives, then you know the proof is flawed.